# Android Gcm Not working with ROR

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I read basic example for implementing google gcm. I developed small client side android application which successfully gives me registration id from gcm server.. now on server side I am using Ruby on rails hence we use this gem for implementing server side of gcm https://github.com/dondeng/gcm_on_rails. I pass my registration id to to my server.
I successfully ran these commands

> > device = Gcm::Device.create(:registration_id => "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
> >
> > notification = Gcm::Notification.new
> >
> > notification.device = device
> >
> > notification.collapse_key = "updates_available"
> >
> > notification.delay_while_idle = true
> >
> > notification.data = {:registration_ids => ["RegistrationID"], :data => {:message_text => "Get on cloud nine"}}
> >
> > notification.save

used to deliver notifications:

```
$ rake gcm:notifications:deliver
```

my rake command running without any error. But after completion of all these tasks my device not receiving any message.. I don't know whats going on in background. How to confirm that sent message properly receive by device.. Need Help... Thank you....

Answer (score 1):

Debugging [GCM](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html) messages can be cumbersome and difficult.

One possible reason is a wrong [API key for GCM](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html#access-key), which must be defined in the configuration files. If you use the wrong API key, then you might get a success response from the server `{:code=>200, :message=>nil}`, although no message has been sent. In this case go to the [Google API Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/) and look up the right key.

Another possible reason is a wrong `REGISTRATION_ID` for the device. if the REGISTRATION_ID is not correct you may get an **NotRegistered** or **InvalidRegistration** error, which is not always recognized by the gcm_on_rails plugin (at the moment). Use the following curl command to debug the API through the console (insert your API_KEY and the `REGISTRATION_ID` of the device).

```
curl --header "Authorization: key=API_KEY" \
     --header Content-Type:"application/json" \ 
     https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send  \
     -d "{\"registration_ids\":[\"REGISTRATION_ID\"],
          \"data\":{\"message_text\":\"Test, Test\"}}"
```

A successful / unsuccessful attempt to call the Gcm API should look like this:

```
{"multicast_id":7961..,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":1,
 "results":[{"registration_id":"..","message_id":"0:.."}]}

{"multicast_id":7961..,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,
 "results":[{"error":"NotRegistered"}]}
```

Finally another reason is an invalid key in the day: do not use a reserved word like `message_type` as a key in the data hash. It will return a status code 200, but it will not deliver any notification. `message_type` is one of the [advanced options](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html) (took me more than an hour to find that out).

Answer (score 0):

If you have no error on server-side, maybe you are not handling correctly the event in your Android App.

Follow this guidelines: http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html#android-app, and write logs for debug.

Comment: Hi manelizzard Thank you for reply... according to above link I already pull all required permissions in androidmanifest.xml. and my client side android application contains two java files one which is  **GCMIntentService.java** extends **GCMBaseIntentService** and another is **mainactivity.java**.  When I run this client side application it run without any error and also gives me regId... But not receiving any notification from server... Any thing else which I missed out at client side....

Comment: I successfully implement server site part and client side part using this tutorial http://androidv5.wordpress.com/2012/08/15/how-to-implement-google-cloud-messaging/ and it also showing me that user register successfully but when I tried to send message to user it gives me error **Servlet SendAllMessagesServlet is not available**

Comment: That's a server-side error. Do you have the class `SendlAllMessagesServlet.java` [here](http://code.google.com/searchframe#76pVTUyLnDo/samples/gcm-demo-server/src/com/google/android/gcm/demo/server/SendAllMessagesServlet.java&q=SendAllMessages%20package:gcm%5C.googlecode%5C.com&ct=rc&cd=1&sq=) and mapped in `web.xml` [here](http://code.google.com/searchframe#76pVTUyLnDo/samples/gcm-demo-server/WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml&q=SendAllMessages%20package:gcm%5C.googlecode%5C.com&ct=rc&cd=3&sq=)?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that this tutorial for server-side is done for Java, no for Ruby on Rails

Comment: I have **SendlAllMessagesServlet.java** also mapped in to **web.xml** but still it giving me same error. Even I create java class and map into web.xml but still giving same error for new class... Need Help.... Thank you......

Comment: hi @nilkash that could be bcz of any file errors. Downloaded the zip from rapidshare, or checked out from google?

Comment: @Santheesh and manelizzad I used **gcm-server-demo** from android sdk examples and now its working fine..... :) Thank you....

Comment: @nilkash I have the same issue..How did you fixed that