# how to get registration_ids on gem 'gcm' rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-cloud-messaging

when i'm following tutorial on [this guide](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/push-notifications/?hl=en), push notifications is working fine and service worker give me valid registration id. But when i implements ruby gem [gcm](https://github.com/spacialdb/gcm), not explained how to generate registration id? and because it i'm always get error :

```
"NotRegistered"
```

this is my code :

```
gcm = GCM.new("secret")
registration_ids= ["secret"]; 
options = {data: {message: "hei dude"}, collapse_key: "messaging"}      

response = gcm.send(registration_ids, options)
```

somebody can help me?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any error with your code based on this [thread](https://github.com/spacialdb/gcm). According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http#response), if you have  `NotRegistered` error, you should remove the registration ID from your server database because the application was uninstalled from the device, or the client app isn't configured to receive messages. See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18621159/on-rapns-how-can-i-know-the-token-for-unregistered-gcm-devices-so-i-can-remove/18621333#18621333) to know the token for unregistered GCM devices and remove them from your database.

You can check this related [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12246514/android-gcm-not-working-with-ror/16773109#16773109) which states that, *"Another possible reason is a wrong `REGISTRATION_ID` for the device. If the `REGISTRATION_ID` is not correct you may get an **NotRegistered** or **InvalidRegistration** error, which is not always recognized by the gcm_on_rails plugin.*